# Insert a row after a date in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Dataframe` like :

```
    date                   col1    col2
0   2022-10-07 04:00:00    x       x1
1   2022-10-08 04:00:00    y       x2
```

I need to update a row (as dictionary) in a specific date **if exist**, and if it does not exist, insert the row next to the closest date.

For this new given date `2022-10-07 05:00:00` (one hour later) and dic `{col1:z}` I would like to get :

```
    date                   col1   col2
0   2022-10-07 04:00:00    x      x1
1   2022-10-07 05:00:00    z      x1
2   2022-10-08 04:00:00    y      x2
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
def write(date,dic):
    m = df['date'] == date
    if m.any():
        df.loc[df['date'] == date, list(dic.keys())] =  list(dic.values()) 
    else:
        df.loc[len(df)] = {**dic, **{'date':date}}
```

Which means that if I can't find the date, I just add the row to the end of the df, **but I want to insert it right after the previous date.**

*(Please also see that since when I insert/update I only have `col1`, so `col2` value will be copied from previous row somehow with `ffill`)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the date as index and update like:

```
df1 = df.set_index('date')
df1.loc[new_date, dic.keys()] = dic.values()
df = df1.sort_index().reset_index().ffill()
```

It will insert new date if it doesn't exist. If it exists it will update the record at that index.

Comment: thank you! and how can I ffill (forward fill) the previous value for columns that does not exist in my new data?

Comment: also, is this not slower than just adding a row and sorting with date?

Comment: I just updated code to ffill. Also it shouldn't be slower than inserting/updating one by one column.

Comment: thanks, i meant if it is not slower than just adding row at [-1] as last row and sort the whole df :)

Comment: If your original df is already sorted and you guarantee that your new date is later than the last date then no need to sort. Otherwise you have to sort to keep the dates in order.